# How to get pytest fixture return value in autouse mode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

In the sample code below, how can I get `A()` object in `test_one` function when the fixture is in `autouse` mode?

```py
import pytest
import time

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.abc = 12
        

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def test_foo():
    print('connecting')
    yield A()
    print('disconnect')
    
    
def test_one():
    #how can i get A() object?
    print([locals()])
    assert 1 == 1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can always add the fixture as parameter despite the `autouse`:

```py
def test_one(test_foo):
    print(test_foo)
    assert 1 == 1
```

If you don't want to use the fixture parameter for some reason, you have to save the object elsewhere to be able to access it from your test :

```py
a = None 

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def test_foo():
    global a
    a = A() 
    yield
    a = None
    
def test_one():
    print(a)
    assert 1 == 1
```

This could be made a little better if using a test class and put `a` in a class variable to avoid the use of the global var, but the first variant is still the preferred one, as it localizes the definition of the object.

Apart from that, there is no real point in yielding an object you don't have access to. You may consider if `autouse` is the right option for your use case. Autouse is often used for stateless setup / teardown.

If your use case is to do some setup/teardown regardless (as suggested by the connect/disconnect comments), and give optional access to an object, this is ok, of course.

Comment: I know this method, but i don't like to pass `test_foo` parameter to `test_one` every time when i write a new test function.